# Assuming Refine does not work for all If[] expression part

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

One simple example as following

```
expr = If[RealAbs[a - b] < 1/S, 
  Sqrt[RealAbs[a - b]/S] + RealAbs[a - b], 1]

Assuming[ a <= b   && S > 0, Refine[expr]] // FullSimplify
```

get

```
If[b < a + 1/S, Sqrt[RealAbs[a - b]/S] + RealAbs[a - b], 1]
```

there is still RealAbs[]

after add PiecewiseExpand

```
Assuming[ a <= b   && S > 0 , Refine[expr]] // 
  FullSimplify // PiecewiseExpand
```

output

[image]

example from ref/Refine

```
Assuming[x >= 0 && y < 0, 
 If[TrueQ[Refine[x - y > 0]], Refine[Sqrt[x^2 y^2]], 0]]
```

Maybe let Refine operate on every expression in If[].

However it is a little tedious, for I have many piecewise expressiones. And I  generate them  implicitly  stored in variables.

Comment: `If` is 3 arguments function. try `expr=If[RealAbs[a-b]<1/S,Sqrt[RealAbs[a-b]/S]+RealAbs[a-b],1,"dont know"]` and see the difference. So it looks like it could not decide, so it returned the same input. Also help says that `"RealAbs gives the absolute value of the real number x` but here you do not have real number as its argument. I also noticed that it can't decide since `S` has no value. How is it going to know if `RealAbs[a - b] < 1/S` ?

Comment: It basically returns the whole `If` expression if it can't decide. It will not return part of it evaluated and part not evaluated.

Comment: add "dont know" and "RealAbs[a - b] < 1/S" ,  output  "dont know".

Comment: adding "dont know" will return "dont know", right? Will not return the input back. This is just to confirm that Mathematica is not able to decide it is true or false.

Comment: yes, always return  "dont know",  it seems to have been already evaluated.

Comment: it looks like `PiecewiseExpand` is doing something extra. strange result though.